# How do I force the code not to required to run on earlier Dart version (earlier than Dart 2.2)?

Tags: dart, literals

I got Dart version 2.9.0. And my flutter is running with that version now.
However, I got this message:

> Set literals weren't supported until version 2.2, but this code is required to be able to run on earlier versions

But I don't want it to be required to run on Dart versions earlier than 2.2.

How do I force it to run only on versions after 2.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the dart sdk constraints in your `pubspec.yaml` file to only use dart versions 2.2 and later.

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.2.0 <3.0.0'
```

See [this site](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec) for more information about the `pubspec.yaml` file.